# drag svg child after zoom via angular

Tags: angular-material, svgpanzoom

I have two circles in an SVG. the SVG is draggable (with angular9 and material) and can zoom on it via changing the scale. in normal zoom (100%) circles are dragged into SVG very good, but when set new scale for example 1.5 on SVG, circles are dragged Unusually such as bellow image :

dragged not in mouse position!

[image]

and image in normal zoom (100%)

[image]

How can I fix this problem?